# JavaScript addEventListener not attaching on page load to anchor tags

Tags: javascript

I'm working on fixing some JavaScript I setup for a custom popup modal feature. What I am trying to do is attach a click event to all anchor tags with the class style-select when the page loads. However, I have not been able to get this to work. I put in a set alert inside the .addEventListener function but it never gets triggered.

Here is the code:

```
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    document.querySelectorAll('.style-select').forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("clicked");
        })
    });
```

I'm not as familiar with JavaScript as I used to be, so this has me stuck. The weird thing is, if I test this functionality in the Chrome dev tools console, I can get the alert to appear. What am I missing to get this functionality work outside of the dev console?

Important side note: NO jQuery answers, please. I can't use jQuery for this project so jQuery or jQuery plugins won't resolve the issue.

Comment: In general, if something is working from the console but not from a .js file, it often means that your code is either not triggered at all, or it is triggered but before the elements you target have been created. It can't be known by looking at your snippet, if you can provide a plnkr, it'd be easier.

Comment: Works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/Lcs50rjj/ Check to make sure your script isn't running before the DOM has loaded. Check the developer console for errors too.

Comment: Rather than modify the NodeList API (not recommended) just to use forEach(), you can just loop through the NodeList and attach the event listeners. If you really want forEach, just convert the NodeList to an array:  var nodesArray = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".style-select"));

Comment: Ah, ok, well, it looks like it the JS was not in the correct spot for some reason. I moved it to the bottom of the document and now it seems like it's doing what it should....